# Function that checks if two arrays are identical

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi there guys and girls,

I have made a function that double checks if the same numbers in two different arrays are present, if there is a repeated number in the array that doesn't matter.

Here is my function:

```
bool sameSet(int arrA[], int arrB[], int sizeA, int sizeB) {
  int temp;
  if (sizeA < sizeB) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
      bool exist = false;

      for (int j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) {
        if (arrA[i] == arrB[j]) {
          exist = true;
          break;
        }  // end of if
      }    // end of second for loop

      if (!exist) return false;

    }  // end of first loop

    return true;
  }

  else {
    temp = sizeA;
    sizeA = sizeB;
    sizeB = temp;

    // cout << "\nSize A is " << sizeA << " Size B is " << sizeB;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
      bool exist = false;

      for (int j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) {
        if (arrA[i] == arrB[j]) {
          exist = true;
          break;
        }  // end of if

      }  // end of second for loop

      if (!exist) return false;

    }  // end of first loop

    return true;
  }
}
```

In my main I am currently just hardcoding because all I need working currently is the function. So in the main it looks like:

```
int sizea = 10, sizeb = 15;
int a[] = {1, 3, 9, 16, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 16};
int b[] = {3, 9, 16, 9, 16, 16, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 16, 3};
cout << "The elements of the arrays a and b ";
if (!sameSet(a, b, sizea, sizeb)) {
  cout << "do not ";
}
cout << "form the same set.";
```

However you would assume because the number 4 in array b is not present in array a that it would return the "`do not for the same set`", however rather frustratingly it doesn't. I get `"does form the same set"`. I believe it is to do with my if statements in the function but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: *the number 4 in array b is not present in array a* - Check that again.

Comment: @chris sorry I have fixed it now, cheers.

Comment: Fix the **indentation** of your code too! :)

Comment: Now consider the arrays contain 100,000 numbers.  You would be looping, worst case, 10,000,000,000 times.  Sounds inefficient, doesn't it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand this however, with out assignment testing program it only works this way :) I agree with you It's quite inefficient.

Comment: You can just write `return true;` or `return false;` at any point, without all these shenanigans around the `exist` variable

Comment: @Miguel_S -- Consider [this](http://ideone.com/616red)

Comment: I think you might need to re-evaluate your understanding of the word "_identical_". Testing for _truly identical_ arrays is quite easy to implement efficiently. However, if you want to test whether they contain the same elements, but not necessarily identical: the fastest option requires keeping a third collection of the unique numbers in each array.

Answer (score 1):

If you change from a fixed array to a container then you can take advantage of the standard algorithm library routines, namely the set functions of `include` or `set_intersection`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};
    std::vector<int> v3{  2,    5,  7};
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    std::sort(v3.begin(), v3.end());

    std::vector<int> v_intersection;
    std::vector<int> v_includes;

    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection));

    for(int n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n";    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::includes(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v3.begin(), v3.end());
}
```

Comment: Using containers should always be advocated, but it is not a prerequisite for STL algorithms. You could stick to plain C-arrays and use pointers to start and `end+1` as iterators. Of course `std::array` would then be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

With std, you may simply write it:

```
bool isSameSet(const int arrA[], const int arrB[], int sizeA, int sizeB)
{
    const std::set<int> setA{arrA, arrA + sizeA};
    const std::set<int> setB{arrB, arrB + sizeB};

    return setA == setB;
}
```

Comment: @graham.reeds: From what I understand, OP wants to check for equality, not inclusion. we have "identical" from title, and name of its function is `sameSet` and from it example `setA` is included in `setB`, but I understand that OP expect *"not equal"* whereas it has *"equal"*.

Comment: My apologies, I skim read the question, formulated my answer and posted.  It was under the same assumption that I read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you are using is flawed.

Let's say that `sizeA` is less than `sizeB`. The code you have checks whether every element in `a` is in `b`. It does not check whether every element in `b` is in `a`. In essence, you are checking whether `a` is a subset of `b`, not whether `a` and `b` are equal as sets.

What you need is:

```
bool sameSet(int arrA[], int arrB[], int sizeA, int sizeB)
{
   // Check whether every element of A is in B
   for(int i=0; i<sizeA; i++){
      bool exist = false;

      for(int j=0; j<sizeB; j++){
         if(arrA[i] == arrB[j]) {
            exist = true;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (!exist) return false;
   }

   // Check whether every element of B is in A
   for(int i=0; i<sizeB; i++){
      bool exist = false;

      for(int j=0; j<sizeA; j++){
         if(arrB[i] == arrA[j]) {
            exist = true;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (!exist) return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

You can refactor the function a little bit to avoid duplicating the logic.

```
// Function to check whether A is a subset of B
bool isSubSet(int arrA[], int arrB[], int sizeA, int sizeB)
{
   // Check whether every element of A is in B
   for(int i=0; i<sizeA; i++){
      bool exist = false;

      for(int j=0; j<sizeB; j++){
         if(arrA[i] == arrB[j]) {
            exist = true;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (!exist) return false;
   }

   return true;
}

// Function to check whether A and B are same sets
bool sameSet(int arrA[], int arrB[], int sizeA, int sizeB)
{
   return ( isSubSet(arrA, arrB, sizeA, sizeB) &&
            isSubSet(arrB, arrA, sizeB, sizeA) );
}
```

Comment: How would I go about this then, would I use another for loop to check whether a and b are equal.

Answer (score 0):

All of the solution so far seem to have O(N^2) time complexity; you can do it in **O(N*logN)** time by using a map:

```
bool sameSet(int arrA[], int arrB[], int sizeA, int sizeB) 
{
   std::map<int,bool> mapA;
   std::map<int,bool> mapB;

   for (int i=0; i<sizeA; i++)
   {
      mapA[arrA[i]] = true;   
   } 

   for (int i=0; i<sizeB; i++)
   {
      mapB[arrB[i]] = true;
   }

   if (mapA.size() != mapB.size())
      return false;

   std:map<int,bool>::const_iterator i, j;
   for(i = mapA.begin(), j = mapB.begin(); i != mapA.end(); ++i, ++j)
   {
     if(*i != *j)
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

You can even do it in **O(N)** time complexity if you use an unordered_map (the rest of the logic holds).

Comment: Your claim of `O(N)` is flawed. You have to account for the cost of constructing the maps, which is `O(N*log(N))`.

Comment: You would need to use an `unordered_map`.